# Update formatted date string to UTC value

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

Users are able to submit only the date part of a date stamp e.g. `2020-12-01`, assuming that the time will be `00:00:00`

So, if I have the above value, I want to update the time to its UTC value. So if I am in the EST timezone, I want to convert `2020-12-01` to `2020-12-01 05:00:00` to account for the five hour offset.

Can I do this with `date-fns-tz`?

```
const { zonedTimeToUtc, format } = require("date-fns-tz");

const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc(new Date("2020-12-01"), tz);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `${format(
  utcDate,
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
)}
`;
```

The above yields `2020-11-30 19:00:00`, which is moving the time 5 hours in the wrong direction.

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hoover-dn417?file=/src/index.js:23-301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc(new Date("2020-12-01"), tz);
```

The built–in parser will be used to parse the string, so it will be parsed as UTC, then date-fns will apply the offset for the *tz*. Don't do that, use:

```
const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc("2020-12-01", tz);
```

so that date-fns parses the string using the *tz*. Now `utcDate.toISOString()` produces "2020-12-01T05:00:00.000Z", which is the equivalent UTC date and time where *tz* is America/New_York.

Date-fns seems to always use the host timezone offset for output, the *timeZone* option just changes the text offset, it doesn't modify the actual timestamp values. Likely you have to use *utcToZonedTime* first to adjust the Date. I struggle with date-fns, I find the documentation seriously lacking in useful examples.

I'd just use *toISOString* and remove the "T" and "Z".